# Function generation process in procedure-oriented programming

Tags: python, oop, function, rdf, triples

I have asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11453352/1465156) about converting a pile of RDF-triples to multiway array representation. My solution looks unwieldy and ...ugly. I try to use function in my solution but I find it is unnecessary since the advantages of using function are not obvious. I think perhaps my programming thinking is procedure-oriented, not OOP.

Here is my solution: (This is the original version without any function)

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import ones
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

s = []
p = []
o = []

# format of each line in 'test.txt' is (subject, predicate, object)
# extract sub, pre and obj in each line then stored in s, p, o, respectively.
for row in open('test.txt'):
    s.append(row.split('(')[1].split(',')[0])   
    p.append(row.split('(')[1].split(', ')[1])
    o.append(row.split(')')[0].split(', ')[2])

# create mapping from indexes to entities
l = s + o
mapping = { v:i for (i, v) in enumerate(sorted(set(l))) }    
mapping_p = { v:i for (i, v) in enumerate(sorted(set(p))) }

# get lists contain [indexes, entities] from initial lists s, p, o 
n_s = [ [mapping[v], v] for v in s ]
n_p = [ [mapping_p[v], v] for v in p ]
n_o = [ [mapping[v], v] for v in o ]

# create the coodinate of each list 
cood_s = []
cood_p = []
cood_o = []

# get the index of s[i], p[i], o[i] and stored in cood_s, cood_p, cood_o, respectively
for i in range(len(n_s)):
    cood_s.append(n_s[i][0])    
    cood_p.append(n_p[i][0])
    cood_o.append(n_o[i][0])
cood = zip(cood_s, cood_o, cood_p)
data = [ list(i) for i in cood ]
m = len(set(p))    # m is the number of predicates
data1 = []

# data1: a list contains ndarrays, each of which records the coodinate of the entity-to-entity matrix 
for i in range(m):    
    data2 = []   
    for j in range(len(data)):
        if data[j][2] == i: data2.append(data[j])
    data1.append(np.array(data2))

T = []    
n = len(set(l)) # n is the number of entities

# generates the coordinate matrix of each predicate as a ndarray then appends to T
for i in range(m):
    T.append( np.array(coo_matrix((ones(len(data1[i])), (data1[i][:, 0], data1[i][:, 1])), shape = (n, n)).todense() ))
```

OK, I hope you're not getting bored, then I use functions to join some statements together, as follows:

```
def split_data_matrix(filename):
    s = []
    p = []
    o = []
    l = []
    for row in open(filename):  
        s.append(row.split('"')[1])
        o.append(row.split('"')[3])
        p.append(row.split('(')[0])
    l = s + o
    return s, o, p, l
s, o, p, l = split_data_matrix('test.txt')

def generate_mapping(l, p):
    mapping = { v:i for (i, v) in enumerate(sorted(set(l))) }
    mapping_p = { v:i for (i, v) in enumerate(sorted(set(p))) }
    n_s = [ [mapping[v], v] for v in s ]
    n_p = [ [mapping_p[v], v] for v in p ]
    n_o = [ [mapping[v], v] for v in o ]
    return n_s, n_p, n_o
n_s, n_p, n_o = generate_mapping(l, p)

def generate_index(n_s, n_p, n_o):
    cood_s = []
    cood_p = []
    cood_o = []
    for i in range(len(n_s)):
        cood_s.append(n_s[i][0])
        cood_p.append(n_p[i][0])
        cood_o.append(n_o[i][0])
    cood = zip(cood_s, cood_o, cood_p)
    data = [ list(i) for i in cood ]
    return data
data = generate_index(n_s, n_p, n_o)

def generate_coordinate(data):
    data1 = []
    m = len(set(p))

    for i in range(m):
        data2 = []
        for j in range(len(data)):
            if data[j][2] == i: data2.append(data[j])
        data1.append(np.array(data2))
    return data1
data1 = generate_coordinate(data)

def generate_ndarrays(data1):
    T = []
    n = len(set(l))
    m = len(set(p))

    for i in range(m):
        T.append( np.array(coo_matrix((ones(len(data1[i])), (data1[i][:, 0], data1[i][:, 1])), shape = (n, n)).todense() ))
    return T
T = generate_ndarrays(data1)
```

My function generation process is simple: I just join some functional similarity lines together then define a function on it. I don't quite sure about whether my way is reasonable. Can someone tell me how to deal with it? Any comment would be welcomed.

Comment: Sorry but this looks too complicated and slow.  If you give inputs (e.g. a few lines of test.txt) and describe your desired output (e.g. sparse matrix) there is probably a much easier, and faster route.

Comment: @fishiwhj Did you ever get this working?